# Validating field length by making use of Jooq and JPA's @Column annotation

Tags: java, validation, jpa, jooq

I am trying to validate the data input by the user by making use of JSR 303 validations.  One validation that I am trying to implement is to check that the size of the inputted value for each field does not exceed the maximum size of the corresponding column.

In order to map a field to a database column I am making use of JPA's `@Column` annotation as follows:

```
@ComplexValidation
public class Person {

    @Column(table = "PERSON_DETAILS", name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

}
```

The `@ComplexValidation` annotation on the Person class, is a JSR 303 custom constraint validator that I am trying to implement, which basically tries to carry out the following steps:

1. Retreives all fields in the class annotated with `@Column` annotation
2. It extracts the table name from the annotation and uses it to load the corresponding JOOQ generated class representing the table
3. It extracts the field name from the annotation and uses it to load the data type and size for the corresponding column

Is there any way in Jooq where I can retrieve the Jooq Generated class based on the table name?  My first attempt can be found below, however it does not work since `table(tableName)` returns an SQLTable not a TableImpl object:

```
Column columnAnnotation = field.getDeclaredAnnotation(Column.class);
if (columnAnnotation != null) {
    String tableName = columnAnnotation.table();
    String fieldName = columnAnnotation.name();

    TableField tableField = (TableField) ((TableImpl) table(tableName)).field(fieldName);
    int columnLength = tableField.getDataType().length();

    if (fieldValue.length() > columnLength) {
        constraintValidatorContext
            .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("exceeded maximum length")
            .addPropertyNode(field.getName())
            .addConstraintViolation();
    }
}
```

Any other suggestions are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only have one generated schema (e.g. `PUBLIC`), you can access tables from there:

```
Table<?> table = PUBLIC.getTable(tableName);
```

See [`Schema.getTable(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Schema.html#getTable-java.lang.String-)